# how to Simplify the expression $\sqrt{(\cos(t))^{(\frac{4}{n}-2)}(sin(t))^2+(\sin(t))^{(\frac{4}{n}-2)}(\cos(t))^2}$

Tags: calculus

I would like to simplify the expression 
$$\sqrt{(\cos(t))^{(\frac{4}{n}-2)}(sin(t))^2+(\sin(t))^{(\frac{4}{n}-2)}(\cos(t))^2}$$
where $n \geq 1$ is a natural numbers

this is not a homework, thank you

Answer (score 1):

As $n\ge1,$

$\dfrac4n-2\le2$

$$c^{(4/n)-2}s^2+s^{(4/n)-2}c^2=(cs)^{(4/n)-2}(s^{4-(4/n)}+c^{4-(4/n)})$$

Answer (score 1):

The best you can get is:

$$|cos(t) \cdot sin(t)| \cdot \sqrt{\cos(t)^{\frac 4n-4} + \sin(t)^{\frac 4n-4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I have for the radicand
$$\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t)\left(\cos^{4/n-4}(t)+\sin^{4/n-4}(t)\right)$$